# Sandbox App File Access Type Location Writing Files

Tags: objective-c, macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I am testing file access on macOS Big Sur Xcode Obj-C with a sandboxed app. Because the app is sandboxed, I had to give read/write access to the folder my app writes files to  - in this case the user's Music Directory.

This is located at Targets / Signing & Capabilities in the Info Tab under App Sandbox and File Access Type.

My app is writing files using:

```
NSString* fileLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Music/Sample Files", NSHomeDirectory()];
```

This all works file. My sandbox app has no problems working with files within the user's /Music/Sample Files/ folder.

My question is: if the user has moved their default Music folder location (which I believe is an option in macOS?) I don't think this would worlk. Since my app has `~/Music/Sample Files`  - how can I write it so that it would still work if the user has moved their default Music Folder to somewhere else?

Bonus question: Why are the file access options so limited in the File Access Type for a sandbox app? It seems to be limited to Downloads / Pictures / Music / and Movies folders. Shouldn't the user's Documents folder (at the very least) be included in this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I believe Music is a folder that can't be removed even if a music library is moved via the Music app. I guess if a music library is moved or changed, the default Music folder will still remain and usable by the app.

Therefore,

```
NSString* fileLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Music/Sample Files", NSHomeDirectory()];
```

Should work regardless?

https://support.apple.com/en-lb/guide/music/mus69248042d/mac

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100341/is-it-possible-to-remove-or-delete-the-music-folder

Answer (score 1):

Better to use [`NSMusicDirectory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nssearchpathdirectory) in [URLForDirectory of NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1407693-urlfordirectory),

Then store the URL as with a [security scope](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl?language=objc#1663809) so you don't have to ask user after a second launch for access.